# XPath - Require value of an attribute if it exists

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My goal is to go through an XML file (DOM object in memory) and remove all elements that contain a given attribute, but don't contain a certain value. Therefore, I want to return an xpath that will identify all of such elements for removal by, in this case, php.

A representative XML layout:

```
<root>
    <pages>
        <page required_distribution="customers, internal, vendors">
            <id>ID of page</id>
            <name>Name of page with limited scope</name>
            <more>more stuff</more>
        </page>
        <page>
            <id>ID of next page</id>
            <name>Name of next page which has unlimited scope</name>
            <more>More stuff, other elements, etc.</more>
        </page>
    </pages>
    <buttons>
        <button>
            <id>button ID</id>
            <text>button text</text>
        </button>
        <button required_distribution="customers, vendors">
            <id>button ID with limited distribution</id>
            <text>button text</text>
        </button>
    </buttons>
    <innerhtmlblocks>
        <!-- Represents elements that are inner html and pulled in directly 
            without additional XSLT parsing, except to remove the control attribute -->
        <innerhtmlblock id="blockid">
            This is a content page, wherein there is innerhtml such as
            <img src="./image.png" /> images and other elements can be
            included in free form. Theoretically, though, I want to be
            able to show certain
            <div required_distribution="internal">
                content only to certain versions.
            </div>
            <div required_distribution="vendor, customers">
                content that varies by version.
            </div>
        </innerhtmlblock>
    </innerhtmlblocks>
</root>
```

XSLT will provide the transformation from XML to HTML; I want to filter the elements before the XSLT happens, so that I get the resultant XML, with the ficticious distribution of "internal", by selecting and then deleting all of the nodes that do not satisfy my requirements.

```
<root>
    <pages>
        <page required_distribution="customers, internal, vendors">
            <id>ID of page</name>
            <name>Name of page with limited scope</name>
            <more>more stuff</more>
        </page>
        <page>
            <id>ID of next page</id>
            <name>Name of next page which has unlimited scope</name>
            <more>More stuff, other elements, etc.</more>
        <page>
    </pages>
    <buttons>
        <button>
            <id>button ID</id>
            <text>button text</text>
        </button>
    </buttons>
    <innerhtmlblocks>
        <!-- Represents elements that are inner html and pulled in directly 
            without additional XSLT parsing, except to remove the control attribute -->
        <innerhtmlblock id="blockid">
            This is a content page, wherein there is innerhtml such as
            <img src="./image.png" /> images and other elements can be
            included in free form. Theoretically, though, I want to be
            able to show certain
            <div required_distribution="internal">
                content only to certain versions.
            </div>
    </innerhtmlblocks>
</root>
```

In this instance, all elements that have @required_distribution should be checked, and if *$requiredval* ("internal") does not appear, then that node should be removed.

The nearest idea I've come to (courtesty of stack exchange) is:

```
//*[@required_distribution and not(contains(@required_distribution,$requiredval))]
```

I've also tried

```
//*[@required_distribution]/[contains(@required_distribution,$requiredval)]
```

and

```
//*[@required_distribution]/@required_distribution[contains(string(),$requiredval]
```

but to no avail. I've also tried variations of node(), self::, etc., but those were equally unfruitful (and probably poorly written enough to make posting them unhelpful).

Once I do that, I'll delete the control attribute(s) using the XPath, which is the only I know works:

```
//*[@required_distribution]
```

**In summary, my question is how do I select all elements where a given attribute exists, but does not contain a given string?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the comma after internal

```
//*[@required_distribution and not(contains(@required_distribution, 'internal,'))]
```

Attribute values are separated by spaces, not commas. That is why `contains` does not find 'internal'.

Comment: I have no functional reason to require the commas - it just made sense in my head at the time, and I thought that contains() was an instring type function. Thanks! My lack of apostrophes around the string 'internal' threw it off as well - I've corrected that and it works.

Comment: I see no reason why you need to include the comma after `internal` within the quotes. On the contrary: if you require the comma, you will miss those cases where `internal` is the last (or only) value listed.

Comment: I agree - it wouldn't make sense due to losing values where `internal` was at the end. However, for the reason that @Federico mentioned, having the comma in the tag was messing it up. I just pulled the commas out altogether and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

`//*[@required_distribution and not(contains(@required_distribution, 'internal'))]`

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the apostrophes around the string 'internal', and was also using commas where I shouldn't.